# Excel 2003 formula not calculating after changing it in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm using Excel 2003 version.

If I change a formula with VBA such as:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=Sheet2!B:B"
```

sometimes the formula calculates and shows the correct value from cell B1 of Sheet2. However, sometimes it does not. Instead, what shows is still "=Sheet2!B:B" in cell A1 in Sheet1, when it should be the value of cell B1 in Sheet2. Plus, even if I change the format of cell A1 to "General", every time I assign a formula to it via VBA, the format automatically becomes "Text" again.

None of recalculation shortcut keys like <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> work.

Has anyone experienced this problem before? And has anyone found the solution?

Comment: `"=Sheet2!B:B"`? You mean `"=Sheet2!B1"`?

Comment: You can explicitly convert the range to general after assigning the formula  Range("A1").NumberFormat = "general"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    With Range("A1")
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Formula = "=Sheet2!B1"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the format for that cell is getting changed to Text somehow (possibly in another part of your code).

Try putting these lines before your `.Formula = ...` line

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print "Format: " & Range("A1").NumberFormat
    Debug.Print "Value: " & Range("A1").Value
    Debug.Print "Formula: " & Range("A1").Formula
    Range("A1").Formula = "=Sheet2!B:B"
End Sub
```

And check the Immediate pane to see what's going on.

Comment: Format: @
Value: 
Formula:

Comment: i dont have any code that changes format. only changing formula of that A1. i guess this is excel by itself. working like that. and how to use formula in vba if it is not working after, i don't know.

Comment: @Paya, Format of @ means it is Text, so adding `Formula = "=Sheet2!B:B"` will enter that in as text. I would suggest using Siddharth's answer to ensure it always gets set as `General` formatting.

Comment: yeah i done that as he told and this resolved the problem, thank you all guys for helping to figure out.